# Python: max takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python

I am trying to print the max of two lists as such:

```
print max([3,4,5,0]), max([3,4,-5,0], key = abs)
```

and I get the error `"max() takes no keyword arguments"`

I'm using Python 2.4.3

What's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: python 2.4 is ancient, why are you using it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using a python feature not yet supported in Python 2.4. From the [`max()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max):

> Changed in version 2.5: Added support for the optional key argument.

You'll have to use a decorate, undecorate pattern, using a python list comprehension:

```
max([(abs(i), i) for i in [3,4,-5,0]])[1]
```